# Sharepoint - restore single document from database level backup

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, restore, document-library

Have a single Sharepoint webserver backed by a SQL 2005 server. The sharepoint server has a messed up document in a document library and I have a SQL database backup from the day before.

What are my options to get just that document back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SharePoint 2007.  Here's a way to get a document out of the SQL database backup you have.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/field_notes/archive/2008/06/23/recover-documents-from-moss-2007-database.aspx

Are you sure you don't have versioning enabled on the document library or that it's not in the Site Collection Recycle Bin?  That would save a lot of time.

Comment: Versioning is not enabled (but might be after this!). It's not in the recycle bin because it wasn't deleted, it's a Visio diagram and has somehow lost the picture and only kept the stencils when I last saved it. Probably my error. Will try the script, thanks - it looks like exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Brilliant, that did it. For the record, I needed one of the WSS_Content_{numbers} databases.